# If fine tuning produces better performance than feature extraction, is there any advantage of using feature extraction?

Tags: neural-networks, transfer-learning

There are several empirical evidences that show that in transfer learning settings, fine tuning produces better performances than feature extraction. In this context is there any advantage of using feature extraction?

Answer (score 1):

A very common scenario is that we simply do not have the resources or time (or at least it's a get most of the benefit for minimal effort situation) to fine-tune a model appropriately, but can run inference on it to extract features. In that situation, extracting features from a pre-trained model might be good enough for what we want to achieve.

There's also situations where the feature extraction (e.g. last hidden layer of a neural network) may be suitable for certain features (e.g. text fields, images), but other aspects of the data might be better suited to a non-neural-network algorithm. E.g. if we want to predict something for tabular data, but some fields contain text and each row is associated with an image. In such a situation, we might extract features for the text and/or image fields, but then use gradient boosted decisions trees as our prediction model.

Answer (score 0):

If the dataset is of similar nature, the features extracted for the original (possibly very large) dataset, which is conceptually achieved in the first layers of a neural net, should be representative enough for the rest of the neural network to learn. Fine-tuning tunes the final parts of the network to better suit the problem at hand. Here, a feature extraction would mean training, or continuing training, the first layers as well, which is usually not desirable considering the computational cost.